# Autostart .jar executable is not working

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, startup, discord

I want to start my Java Application (a Discord bot) when I boot my windows 10 PC.

To do that. Also, I have a bat file in my Autostart folder with the following:

```
start javaw -Xmx200m -jar D:\Local\bot.jar
EXIT
```

The main of the Java Code has the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
         BotListener NL = new BotListener();
         jda = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).addListener(NL).setToken(BOT_TOKEN).buildBlocking();

        } catch (LoginException | IllegalArgumentException | InterruptedException | RateLimitedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

}
```

I've tried shutting it down and creating a new jda after a delay in a thread, both with the delay in the main thread and in another thread class. I also tried shutting it down and then running the bat file again.

When I run the bat file it works. Only when it's run automatically on startup it fails. I am assuming it's a problem with Java or using a .bat and a .jar or something because restarting the jda worked when I run it myself.

Comment: change your bat file to this: `start javaw -Xmx200m -jar D:\Local\bot.jar > D:\Local\bot.log  2>&1` and look for errors in the log.

Comment: it creates the log file but it's empty even after closing the process